# pass a protocol buffers object by an Android Intent

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

Any **Serializable** or **Parceable** objects can be exchanged by Intent.
But protobuf objects do not implement Serializable or Parceable.
Since protobuf objects implementation may change in the future, it's not advised to modify/extend them.

How to exchange by **Android Intent** data from **protocol buffer message (generated class) ?**

EDIT : I was using protobuf-2.3.0 where [GeneratedMessage](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage.java?r=311) and [GeneratedMessageLite](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite.java?spec=svn407&r=311) don't implement Serializable. Generated messages started to implement Serializable on 2 November 2010. [Protobuf-2.4.1](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list) was released on April 2011.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following answer was true in 2011, but `GeneratedMessageLite` no longer implements `Serializable`. `GeneratedMessage` still does.

[`GeneratedMessage`](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage.java) and [`GeneratedMessageLite`](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite.java) both implement `Serializable`, so you *should* be able to just serialize any specific generated message class as far as I'm aware. Were you trying to serialize just `Message` by any chance?

Comment: Ouch my GeneratedMessage source code is different from google code. One more point for Jon .

Comment: @raychenon: It's entirely possible that it's only a recent change, of course - I didn't check the history to see when it started to implement Serializable.

Comment: I know that is a bit irrelevant, but is there a chance anyone can post a sample code of passing a GeneratedMessage in an intent?

Comment: GeneratedMessageLite doesn't seem to implement `Serializable` anymore.

Comment: @ShubhamJain: Interesting. I'll note that in the answer.

Comment: However, Java-nano used to implement `Parcelable` which could  be used with `Android Parcelable` to send objects between intents. However Java-nano is dead, and `GeneratedMessageLite` doesn't implement either `GeneratedMessageLite` or `Parcelable`. So I'm still not sure what would be the best way to pass objects between intents.

Comment: Found a solution. Adding the answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet while passing i get java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value

Comment: @SubinBabu: I'm afraid that's really not enough information to go on, particularly for a question that's nearly 10 years old. I suggest you ask a question in a new post with much more detail.

Answer (score 4):

For now probably the best way to do this in Java-lite (currently recommended for Android) is convert the object to [ByteArray](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#parsing-and-serialization) and then send it to the Activity and convert the byte Array back to the object in the target activity.

```
// convert to byte array and pass to intent

Intent listResults = new Intent(activity, ImageResults.class);

listResults.putExtra( "reply", reply.toByteArray());


// Convert byte array to Object
 result_list = (Search.SearchResponse) Search.SearchResponse.parseFrom(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("reply"));
```

Java-nano used to implement `Parcelable` which could be used with `Android Parcelable` to send objects between Activities. However Java-nano is no longer, and `GeneratedMessageLite` doesn't implement either `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.